# BigDecimal.divide(...) - appropriate scale for quotients with non-terminating expansions

Tags: java, floating-point, bigdecimal

I'm using `BigDecimal` for some floating-point math. If you divide `5` by `4.2` you'll get an exception (as the result has a non-terminating expansion which cannot be represented by a `BigDecimal`) i.e.

```
BigDecimal five = new BigDecimal("5");
BigDecimal fourPointTwo = new BigDecimal("4.2");
five.divide(fourPointTwo) // ArithmeticException: Non-terminating decimal expansion; no exact representable decimal result.
```

I'm prepared to lose some precision in this case, so I am going to use the `divide(...)` method which allows a scale for the result to be provided:

```
five.divide(fourPointTwo, 2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP); //Fine, but obviously not 100% accurate
```

What scale should I pass to this method so that the result is as accurate as if I had performed the calculation using two `doubles`?

Comment: So you don't have a concrete accuracy requirement?

Comment: If you accuracy requirement is "as good as `double`", wouldn't it be easier just to *use* `double`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [javadocs of the BigDecimal class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html):

> If zero or positive, the scale is the number of digits to the right of the decimal point. If negative, the unscaled value of the number is multiplied by ten to the power of the negation of the scale. The value of the number represented by the BigDecimal is therefore (unscaledValue × 10<sup>-scale</sup>).

The precision of `double` varies accordingly to the order of magnitude of the value. According to [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#doubleToLongBits%28double%29), it uses 52 bits to store the unsigned mantissa, so any integer that may be represented with 52 bits will be ok. This will be roughly 18 decimal digits.

Further, `double` uses 11 bits to store the exponent. So, something like 4 decimal precision will do. This way, any integer up to 52 bits multiplied by a positive or negative power of 2 with at most 10 bits may be represented (one bit is the sign of the expoent). Beyond that, you start to lose precision.

The extra bit of `double` stores the sign.

This way, scale 18 + 4 = 22 will be at least as precise as `double`.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is called "round-off error" or "rounding error". Example:

You have two numbers `a` and `b`. You know that each has a certain precision (i.e. number of digits that you're confident of) which means that every other digit is "random" noise.

Imagine `b` has a precision of two digits. The result of `(b*100)-int(b*100)` will be random since the operation cuts away all "correct" digits.

These errors propagate depending on the mathematical operation. Some examples:

- Errors margins add when the numbers are added. If `a` and `b` have a precision of two, adding them might turn the second digit of the fraction into garbage: 0.003 + 0.008 = 0.011
- Multiplication grows the error fast and exponential functions grow it even faster.
- Division reduces the error margin (0.003 / 3 = 0.001)

So if you want a correct answer, you must calculate the error margins of all operations in your code following the rules outlined above. **Link anyone?**

Of course, this is usually not an option. So you need to think what amount of error you can live with. For example if you do math on financial data, a precision of 10 or 20 is generally enough because you have enough bits to "waste" for several mathematical operations before the error grows into significant parts of the value.

Example: You start with `10.500 000 000` and `3.100 000 000`. If you divide the two, you get `3.387 096 774`. From that, you only need `3.87` - the rest is spare precision which you can use up in further operations until you round the last result to two digits and save it back in the database.

Comment: I'm not a native English speaker, so I might got some terms wrong but I hope you get the idea.